# No display and blinking underscore in the upper left corner

Tags: hard-drive

I have this IDE hard disk drive. I installed Windows XP. After the post, I got no display and a blinking underscore in the upper left corner.

The hard disk drive is set to master and 1st priority and well connected but still the same problem occurs.

When I plug the hard disk in another system, it boots and runs Windows XP. Why?

Comment: It it a WD harddrive? In which case you want to set it to SINGLE, not to master. ( Master means that there are two drives on the cable. Most drives seem to work fine when incorrectly set to master when they should be set to single, but WD drives adhere to the standard).

Comment: People won't e-mail you with an answer. Please consider sticking around – this is a public question & answer site, where posts should be useful to a public audience.

Comment: Are there any USB devices connected?  I have seen this when a USB DVD was connected .  The system would sit for about 45 minutes and finally boot.  Never found reason but removing the USB device resolved immediately. Also had it once with  a USB memory stick

Answer (score 0):

i think i have a problem with the mother board or hard drive because i try to format it with windows xp i got no display same if i try to run it with a third party software's like hirens, u boot, still there is no display, but i manage to format it with windows xp and run it with a third party software's by removing the hard drive of the "original" system unit and  plug it to other system units and it works fine, so i think the mother board is the problem but when i try to plug  other hard drive with already formatted windows xp on it  and i even reformat it again  with windows xp to the motherboard of the original system unit it works fine as well  and there's no problem. So im confused if it was the mother board or the hard drive is the problem. (by the way I use the same cd/dvd drive so theres no problem with the cd/dvd drive)

So the summary of what just I did is I format the hard disk drive with windows xp to other system unit and return the hard disk to the original system unit and it works. (i did this 2x already and my client came back after  3 weeks and complain the same problem) So I tell my client to observe again if there will be no display and blinking underscore again once he turn on again his system unit you'll just earn money and we will just buy new hard disk drive SATA and will just make the old 80 gb IDE as a slave so that he can still use the old ide hard disk as a extra drive or storage.